# how to solve:Exception: The version of Kivy installed on this system is too old.(You have 2.2.0, but the application requires 2.2.1)

Tags: kivy, kivymd

Trying to run a kivymd app but it brings up the error message Exception: The version of Kivy installed on this system is too old.(You have 2.2.0, but the application requires 2.2.1)

I have made changes to the kivymd **init**.py file as well but still the issue persists. also tried to update kivy but the latest one is 2.2.0. I have kivymd v1.1.1 and kivy v2.2.0 installed on my system

Comment: Hi , I realized one small mistake that I made and I forgot to check. The version that I have mentioned in .kv file was 2.2.1 that I have put and that's why it was not working. Corrected to 2.2.0 in .kv file "#:kivy 2.2.0" it was a silly mistake on my part, I tend to overlook. The issue is resolved for me and it is working now.